# Why does setMargins() not work on buttons?

Tags: android

Why does setMargins() not work on buttons?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhE7B.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
        gridLayout.setRowCount(5);
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(7);
    setContentView(gridLayout);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
        layoutParams.setMargins(10,10,10,10);

    for(int i=1;i<31;i++) {
        Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            button.setTextSize(18);
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
        gridLayout.addView(button,layoutParams);
    }



}
}
```

Comment: While it is fine to post a screenshot of an application / web page, posting screenshot of code should be avoided for [many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Please edit your question to add the relevant code. If possible produce a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you please put your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you use ConstraintLayout in your layout you should make sure your button had chain from that side you want have margin 
example

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
 />
```

if you dont write

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

in your Button's tag you cant set margin from bottom
and otherside like this.